# Any command line utility (like wget,curl etc) and/or java methods to get meta data of a shortened URL?

Tags: java, url, curl, web, web-crawler

I have stream of shortened URLs as received from twitter feeds. I don't need entire page of that URL, but basic meta information like expanded original URL, page title, timestamps etc. I can get the entire page containing these meta as well using curl,wget, but any quicker way to only get the meta? Also, is there any java classes/methods to do this like curl.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Head requests may be what you are looking for, here is an example that uses curl (in its Python implementation though): [Python: Convert those TinyURL (bit.ly, tinyurl, ow.ly) to full URLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748324/python-convert-those-tinyurl-bit-ly-tinyurl-ow-ly-to-full-urls)